# Label output in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In querystring value I have always the string **YEAR-MONTH (2014-07)** and I use the string format method to have in output **Juli 2014** in **GridView** with **RowDataBound** event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Month"]))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = string.Format(new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                                              "{0:MMMM yyyy}", 
                                            DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Month"));
        }
    }
}
```

If invoke with **asp:ImageButton ID="SendImg"** the **protected void Sendmonth** the output below for **Label Month** and **key** string are null :

```
protected void Sendmonth(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton SendImg = (ImageButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)SendImg.NamingContainer;
    Label Month = (Label)row.FindControl("Month");
    string key;

    DateTime dt;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(Month.Text.ToString(), "MMMM yyyy",
                   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

    key = "2 >>> " + Month.Text.ToString();

    Response.Write(Month.Text.ToString() + "<br />");
    Response.Write(key.ToString());
    Response.End();
 }
```

This is beginning to make me believe my structure as a whole is not correct.

What am I missing ?

What's wrong with the code?

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

**`.aspx`**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Month">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <center>
            <asp:Label ID="Month" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Month").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
        </center>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sendmonth">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <center>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="SendImg" runat="server" OnClick="Sendmonth" />
        </center>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**`EDIT #1`**

I have tried this solution suggested by [repierre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844006/repierre)

In this case I have in GV the value equals to 2014-07 and the output for **Label Month** and **key** string are correct, but I need show in GV the value Juli 2014.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Month"]))
        {
            var label = e.Row.FindControl("Month") as Label;
            // Check if label is not null
            label.Text = string.Format(new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                                          "{0:MMMM yyyy}", 
                                        DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Month"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be better if you can show what type of data you r binding to GridView and what's the result you would like to get

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried seeing what happens if you rebinding the data to the grid on Postback? That maybe the simplest solution but far from the best.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to the fact that in your `RowDataBound` event handler you're not setting the value of `Month` label; you are setting the text of the grid cell not of the `Month` label:

```
e.Row.Cells[1].Text = string.Format(new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                                          "{0:MMMM yyyy}", 
                                        DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Month"));
```

Try setting the value of the `Month` label:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Month"]))
        {
            var label = e.Row.FindControl("Month") as Label;
            // Check if label is not null
            label.Text = string.Format(new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                                          "{0:MMMM yyyy}", 
                                        DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Month"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq, what is the type of property `Month` of `e.Row.DataItem`? Can you please post a snippet of how that class is defined?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq, also, what does `Request.QueryString["Month"]` have to do with all this? Do you have to display the date from the query string instead of the date from data item?

Comment: the value of **`Month`** is a result of an query in MySQL. This query populated the GridView. What to know more?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq, yes. What is the type of `Month` property? Is it a `DateTime`? Also, try removing the part `Text='<%# Eval("Month").ToString() %>'` from your markup; it's not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Month"]))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = 
                    string.Format(new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                           "{0:MMMM yyyy}", DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Month"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Change to:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Month"]))
        {

            Label Month = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Month");

            Month.Text = string.Format(new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                                              "{0:MMMM yyyy}", 
                                       DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Month"));
        }
    }
}
```

While setting get the label from row and set the text.

I hope this can help you